# MySQL: Update table column using values of same column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table:

```
PriceRange (MinPrice DOUBLE, MaxPrice DOUBLE, TrdDate DATE)
```

I want to apply a multiplication factor on MinPrice and MaxPrice for all the records with TrdDate less than a particular date. For example,

Table before update:

```
(10, 12, 01-JAN-2016)
(12, 14, 02-JAN-2016)
(6, 7, 03-JAN-2016)
```

Table after update (with multiplication factor of 0.5 applied on all records for TrdDate < 03-JAN-2016):

```
(5, 6, 01-JAN-2016)
(6, 7, 02-JAN-2016)
(6, 7, 03-JAN-2016)
```

I know subquery will not work here as I can't update the same record that I am reading.

Can I solve above problem using JOIN or do I have to use cursor for it?

Comment: Is your Date format with '01-JAN-2016' or `01-01-2016` ???

Comment: @SumonSarker, date format is not of much concern.

Comment: @Sumon Sarker: A date has no format; it's just a date (i.e. 2017-07-15 is the same date as July 15, 2017 of course).

Comment: Yes! I know, But he mentioned the date format like that. Because date string comparison is not valid when `01-JAN-2016` and `01-APR-2016` @ThorstenKettner

Comment: @Sumon Sarker: It doesn't matter how the date is *shown* in some output or sample. In the database it is still a mere date. You can compare it to any valid supported date string literal, e.g. `'2016-01-03'`.  It is recommended to use ANSI date literals though: `DATE '2016-01-03'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `UPDATE` query to solve this:

```
UPDATE PriceRange 
SET MinPrice = MinPrice * 0.5, MaxPrice = MaxPrice * 0.5 
WHERE TrdDate < '2016-01-03'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb852946e9f5f5fade8e261ec34b7384)